# How to get menu active item

Tags: php, html, joomla

I have a project that im working on right now.

I have developed it in Joomla, on the index page, I have a menu which shows the year.

I need to know how to code a php variable to get the active item name of this menu so I can show (`echo`) it where I want.

See the attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
$currentMenuId = JSite::getMenu()->getActive()->id ;
```

Name:

```
JSite::getMenu()->getActive()->name;
```

or this

```
$menu = &JSite::getMenu();
$active = $menu->getActive();
$path = isset($active) ? array_reverse($active->tree) : null;
$thisPath = $path[(count($path)-1)];

echo $thisPath; //echo active menu id
```

Comment: This will give me the ID of the menu, I need the name of that menu to be posted, and I have 2 menu in the page, please help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple method and sticking to Joomla coding standards is as follows:

```
$menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();
$title = $menu->getActive()->title;

echo $title;
```